Broken pipe while relaying data with HTTP CONNECT proxy
I am trying to write a simple HTTP CONNECT proxy in go which just blindly forwards the packets back and forth between the client and the target server without looking at them until the tunnel is closed.
type ProxyHttpServer struct {
    Addr string
}

func (proxy *ProxyHttpServer) ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    if r.Method == http.MethodConnect {
        proxy.handleConnect(w, r)
    }
}

func (proxy *ProxyHttpServer) handleConnect(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    // get control of the underlying connection
    hij, ok := w.(http.Hijacker)
    if !ok {
        http.Error(w, "Hijacking not supported", http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }

    // hijack the connection
    clientConn, _, err := hij.Hijack() // connection to the client which sent the request
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }
    defer clientConn.Close()

    // Establish TCP connection to the remote target server
    upstreamConn, err := net.Dial("tcp", r.Host) // TCP connection to aggregator
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusServiceUnavailable)
        return
    }
    defer upstreamConn.Close()

    // TCP connection is established, send 200 OK back to the client
    clientConn.Write([]byte("HTTP/1.1 200 Connection established\r\n\r\n"))

    // set up the data relay between the connection and the outbound stream
    proxy.relayData(clientConn, upstreamConn)
}

func (proxy *ProxyHttpServer) relayData(responseStream io.ReadWriteCloser, outboundStream io.ReadWriteCloser) {
    wg := sync.WaitGroup{}
    wg.Add(2)

    // Transfer data from outboundStream to responseStream.
    go func() {
        defer wg.Done()
        proxy.transfer(responseStream, outboundStream, "outboundStream -> responseStream")
    }()

    // Transfer data from responseStream to outboundStream.
    go func() {
        defer wg.Done()
        proxy.transfer(outboundStream, responseStream, "responseStream -> outboundStream")
    }()

    wg.Wait()
}

func (proxy *ProxyHttpServer) transfer(destination io.WriteCloser, source io.ReadCloser, logMessage string) {
    // copy data from the source to the destination
    n, copyErr := io.Copy(destination, source)
    if copyErr != nil {
        log.Printf("failed to copy data [%s]: %v", logMessage, copyErr)
        return
    }
    log.Printf("successfully copied %v bytes [%s]", n, logMessage)
}

func main() {
    proxy := ProxyHttpServer{
        Addr: ":8887",
    }

    log.Printf("Listening on port %s", proxy.Addr)

    err := http.ListenAndServe(":8887", &proxy)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}

To test this, I have written a small WebSocket client and server program. When I am trying to transfer the data by running the client, I am getting the following error:
2024/10/07 13:28:58 Listening on port :8887
2024/10/07 13:29:08 successfully copied 684 bytes [responseStream -> outboundStream]
2024/10/07 13:29:08 failed to copy data [outboundStream -> responseStream]: writeto tcp 127.0.0.1:33088->127.0.0.1:8080: readfrom tcp 127.0.0.1:8887->127.0.0.1:60268: splice: connection reset by peer
2024/10/07 13:29:16 successfully copied 684 bytes [responseStream -> outboundStream]
2024/10/07 13:29:16 failed to copy data [outboundStream -> responseStream]: writeto tcp 127.0.0.1:51142->127.0.0.1:8080: readfrom tcp 127.0.0.1:8887->127.0.0.1:46066: splice: broken pipe
2024/10/07 13:29:21 successfully copied 1343 bytes [outboundStream -> responseStream]
2024/10/07 13:29:21 failed to copy data [responseStream -> outboundStream]: writeto tcp 127.0.0.1:8887->127.0.0.1:42628: readfrom tcp 127.0.0.1:52260->127.0.0.1:8080: splice: connection reset by peer
2024/10/07 13:29:28 successfully copied 684 bytes [responseStream -> outboundStream]
2024/10/07 13:29:28 failed to copy data [outboundStream -> responseStream]: writeto tcp 127.0.0.1:52268->127.0.0.1:8080: readfrom tcp 127.0.0.1:8887->127.0.0.1:42632: splice: broken pipe

server.go
func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/ws", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        conn, err := websocket.Accept(w, r, &websocket.AcceptOptions{
            InsecureSkipVerify: true, // disabled for testing
        })
        if err != nil {
            log.Println("Failed to accept connection:", err)
            return
        }
        defer conn.Close(websocket.StatusInternalError, "Internal server error")

        ctx := context.Background()

        var msg string
        err = wsjson.Read(ctx, conn, &msg)
        if err != nil {
            log.Println("Failed to read message:", err)
            return
        }

        log.Println("Received message:", msg)

        err = wsjson.Write(ctx, conn, "Hello, client!")
        if err != nil {
            log.Println("Failed to write message:", err)
            return
        }

        conn.Close(websocket.StatusNormalClosure, "Done")
    })

    // Register signal handler to gracefully shutdown server
    go func() {
        sigint := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
        signal.Notify(sigint, os.Interrupt, syscall.SIGTERM)
        <-sigint

        log.Println("Shutting down server...")
        os.Exit(0)
    }()

    certFile := "./cert.pem"   // Path to your SSL certificate
    keyFile := "./private.key" // Path to your SSL private key

    log.Println("Server started on :8080")
    err := http.ListenAndServeTLS(":8080", certFile, keyFile, nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("ListenAndServe:", err)
    }
}

client.go
func main() {
    proxyURL, err := url.Parse("http://127.0.0.1:8887")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Failed to parse proxy URL:", err)
    }

    

    httpTransport := &http.Transport{
        Proxy: http.ProxyURL(proxyURL),
        TLSClientConfig: &tls.Config{InsecureSkipVerify: true},
    }

    httpClient := &http.Client{
        Transport: httpTransport,
    }

    opts := &websocket.DialOptions{
        HTTPClient: httpClient,
    }

    ctx := context.Background()
    conn, err := Dial(ctx, "wss://localhost:8080/ws", opts)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("%v", err)
    }
    defer conn.Close(websocket.StatusInternalError, "Internal server error")

    err = wsjson.Write(ctx, conn, "Hello, server!")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Failed to send message:", err)
    }

    var msg string
    err = wsjson.Read(ctx, conn, &msg)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Failed to read message:", err)
    }

    log.Println("Received message:", msg)

    conn.Close(websocket.StatusNormalClosure, "Done")
}

I believe the proxy is fine but the issue is with client/server program because when I am using curl to access any server via proxy, its working fine.
 curl -x http://127.0.0.1:8887  https://www.reddit.com/ -v                          
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:8887...
* Connected to (nil) (127.0.0.1) port 8887 (#0)
* allocate connect buffer!
* Establish HTTP proxy tunnel to www.reddit.com:443
> CONNECT www.reddit.com:443 HTTP/1.1
> Host: www.reddit.com:443
> User-Agent: curl/7.81.0
> Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 Connection established
< 
* Proxy replied 200 to CONNECT request
* CONNECT phase completed!
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
*  CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
*  CApath: /usr/lib/ssl/certs
...





2024/10/07 13:59:41 Listening on port :8887
2024/10/07 14:00:14 successfully copied 883 bytes [responseStream -> outboundStream]
2024/10/07 14:00:14 successfully copied 27470 bytes [outboundStream -> responseStream]

Thanks!
